# Accuracy assessment in QGIS (Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin) without using random points?

Tags: qgis, classification, accuracy

i am using QGIS with the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I already classified a Sentinel 2a scene by using an supervised classification approach. So I have trained areas all over the scene but I do not want to have an accuracy assessment for the whole scene, but for defined areas in this scene. I want to check every single Pixel in those defined areas (150 - 250 pixel). Does anybody know wether this is possible and if so:

1. It is possible within the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin and how?
   or
2. Do I have to use another tool in QGIS (like Grass, Saga etc.) and which one?

Comment: Clip the result with mask poligon to smaller area